# Naming new java project in Eclipse "Bug"

Tags: eclipse, project

existing project "Swing 1" is in "C:\Users\Anh\eclipse-workspace\Swing1"
and Iam creating a new java project in
a different location : "C:\Users\Anh\Desktop\New folder".
But The Eclipse notify an error when I name the new java project "swing1".

---

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

I guess Eclipse don't know that the "swing1" project which Iam creating  is in different location from the existing "swing1".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse does not allow projects with names that differ only in the case ("swing1" and "Swing1" in your example).

Information about all projects is stored in the workspace in the
`.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.projects` directory. The project name is used for the name of a subdirectory in that directory. Since some file systems don't allow directories that only differ in the case of the name Eclipse must disallow such clashing names.

The actual location of the project doesn't matter as far as this restriction is concerned.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and spending time answering my question!